# jQuery: Check if button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons in a form and want to check which one was clicked.
Everything works fine with radioButtons:

```
if($("input[@name='class']:checked").val() == 'A')
```

On simple submit button everything crash.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code for what you've tried already.

Answer (score 59):

```
$('#submit1, #submit2').click(function () {
   if (this.id == 'submit1') {
      alert('Submit 1 clicked');
   }
   else if (this.id == 'submit2') {
      alert('Submit 2 clicked');
   }
});
```

Comment: @Kautil Typo in your else condition. `submit1` should be `submit2`

Answer (score 22):

You can use this:

```
$("#id").click(function()
{
   $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

Now check it via an if statement:

```
if($("#id").data('clicked'))
{
   // code here 
}
```

For more information you can visit [the jQuery website on the .data() function.](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 8):

```
jQuery(':button').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'button1') {
        alert('Button 1 was clicked');
    }
    else if (this.id == 'button2') {
        alert('Button 2 was clicked');
    }
});
```

EDIT:- This will work for all buttons.

Comment: My tries:

if($("input[@name='submit']:clicked").val() == 'button')

$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
     alert("button with the id: "+$(this).attr("id")+" was clicked!");
});

That works but not good for me, i have more buttons not just one so i need to distinguish it.

I've tried a lot of code and having problems with some because can't put it in if statement because not sure what is return true or 1 or nothing (tried everything). I am searching for the simpliest and similar solution that i have for radio buttons.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target) {
        alert(e.target.id + ' clicked');
    }
});
```

you should tweak this a little (eg. use a name in stead of an id to alert), but this way you have more generic function.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#btn1, #btn2').click(function() {
    let clickedButton = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(clickedButton);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
var focusout = false;

$("#Button1").click(function () {
    if (focusout == true) {
        focusout = false;
        return;
    }
    else {
        GetInfo();
    }
});

$("#Text1").focusout(function () {
    focusout = true;
    GetInfo();
});
```