# Checking if button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to check if (condition) onclick of an event of a button? cause I want to return a value if user click on popupButton

```
function showPopup(){
    popup.style.visibility = "visible";
    popupButton.onclick = ()=>{
        popup.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    popupClose.onclick = () => {
        popup.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }  
}
```

Comment: Return a value when?  From the showPopup method?  If so, then no.  Because the method makes the event handlers that will happen later.  "Later" when they are clicked, that method will have already ended.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain what you are looking for?

Comment: @Taplar I got it ! thanks 
do you have any idea ?

Comment: @PraneetDixit I just want if popupButton is clicked reterned a true value

Comment: Return a true value from what method?

Comment: I recommend you to use an eventlistener. Something like what @mplugjan explained in his answer.

Comment: @Taplar I tried to do it like this But Always returned false

`function showPopup(){
    let ck = false;
    popup.style.visibility = "visible";
    popupButton.onclick = ()=>{
        popup.style.visibility = "hidden";
        ck = true;
    }
    popupClose.onclick = () => {
        popup.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }  
    return ck;
}`

Comment: You can not do what you want to do..... You would have to rethink this either as a promise or a callback.

Comment: @epascarello I see
 thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404890/jquery-check-if-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do  this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("popBut").addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("Open button clicked"); // here you can call something 
    document.getElementById("popup").classList.remove("hide");
  })
  document.querySelector("#popup div.close").addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("Close button clicked"); // here you can call something 
    document.getElementById("popup").classList.add("hide");
  })

})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#popup {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.close {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="popBut">Show</button>

<div id="popup" class="hide"><div class="close">X</div>Here is a popup </div>
```

Comment: Probably because you did not actually answer the question....

Comment: @epascarello Perhaps now?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a return value from an asynchronous call. By the time the return fires the other code has already finished running. You need to use a promise and make the other code wait for a response back before executing.

```js
function askQuestion() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    const msg = document.getElementById("msg");
    const btnYes = document.getElementById("btnYes");
    const btnNo = document.getElementById("btnNo");

    const cleanUp = function() {
      msg.classList.remove("active");
      btnYes.removeEventListener("click", yesFnc);
      btnNo.removeEventListener("click", noFnc);
    }

    const yesFnc = function() {
      resolve(true);
      cleanUp();
    }
    const noFnc = function() {
      resolve(false);
      cleanUp();
    }

    btnYes.addEventListener("click", yesFnc);
    btnNo.addEventListener("click", noFnc);
    msg.classList.add("active");


  });
}

function example1 () {
  askQuestion().then(function(result){
    console.log("The answer was: ", result);
  });
}


async function example2 () {
  const result = await askQuestion()
  console.log("The answer was: ", result);
}

document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("click", example1);
document.getElementById("test2").addEventListener("click", example2);
```

```css
#msg {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1em;
}

#msg.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="test1">Example 1</button>
<button id="test2">Example 2</button>

<div id="msg">
  <h2>Do you like pie?</h2>
  <button id="btnYes" type="button">Yes</button>
  <button id="btnNo" type="button">No</button>
</div>
```